# google apps Authentication (SMTP) failed

Tags: perl, email, authentication, smtp, gmail

I just recently signed up for a domain and an accompanying email address via google.  I was sending emails via an SMTP client (Perl Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail module) successfully on the first day, and then I received a "suspicious login" email from google.  Since then I've not been able to send emails via my SMTP client.  I can still send emails via the browser interface.

Both POP and IMAP are enabled for this email account.

I've tried both ssl and tls using all combinations with ports 587 and 465

I have an "ordinary" gmail address, and that is able to send emails without any issues with my SMTP client.

Here is the output from my "broken" google apps account:

```
Connecting to smtp.gmail.com using ssl with LOGIN on port 465 and timeout of 60
Net::SMTPS>>> Net::SMTPS(0.04)
Net::SMTPS>>>   IO::Socket::INET6(2.72)
Net::SMTPS>>>     IO::Socket(1.36)
Net::SMTPS>>>       IO::Handle(1.34)
Net::SMTPS>>>         Exporter(5.70)
Net::SMTPS>>>   Net::SMTP(3.06)
Net::SMTPS>>>     Net::Cmd(3.06)
Net::SMTPS>>>     IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s51sm12504577ots.23 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-SIZE 35882577 
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250-CHUNKING
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 250 SMTPUTF8
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)>>> AUTH LOGIN
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f94eb1a02c8)<<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    
Authentication (SMTP) failed
```

Here is the output from my working ordinary gmail account:

```
Connecting to smtp.gmail.com using ssl with LOGIN on port 465 and timeout of 60
Net::SMTPS>>> Net::SMTPS(0.04)
Net::SMTPS>>>   IO::Socket::INET6(2.72)
Net::SMTPS>>>     IO::Socket(1.36)
Net::SMTPS>>>       IO::Handle(1.34)
Net::SMTPS>>>         Exporter(5.70)
Net::SMTPS>>>   Net::SMTP(3.06)
Net::SMTPS>>>     Net::Cmd(3.06)
Net::SMTPS>>>     IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-SIZE 35882577
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250-CHUNKING
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250 SMTPUTF8
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> AUTH LOGIN
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> YnVmZmFsb3Rvb2xib3hAZ21haWwuY29t
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> MTExMDBtZXRyaWM=
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 235 2.7.0 Accepted
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> MAIL FROM:<xxx@gmail.com>
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250 2.1.0 OK k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> RCPT TO:<xxx@gmail.com>
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250 2.1.5 OK k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> DATA
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 354  Go ahead k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> From: xxx@gmail.com
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> To: xxx@gmail.com
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> Subject: test
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 07:45:32 -0500
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> MIME-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> TEST<br><br>
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> .
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 250 2.0.0 OK 1468327533 k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)>>> QUIT
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7fe7a61efec8)<<< 221 2.0.0 closing connection k52sm9296344otc.4 - gsmtp
Email sent.
```

Is there some google apps setting I need to adjust to be able to send emails via SMTP again?  Already banging my head for the last day.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Borodin - what about my question earned a negative vote from you?

Comment: *"what about my question earned a negative vote from you?"* I very nearly downvoted your question, but instead tried to improve it. I started to edit your words, but realised that I don't understand your meaning, so all I have changed is the syntax highlighting. Stack Overflow automates syntax colouring according to the prevalent language tag, so in your case everything was coloured as if it were Perl code. I hope you approve? The downvote wasn't mine.

Comment: It would be much easier for me just to downvote your question and move on, but I hoped that you would prefer me to make your words readable and then to ask if my interpretation was correct. I will leave your question as it is, but I am certain that your question will be overlooked without improvement.

Comment: Borodin - My apologies.  Thought you downvoted me.  Anyways after contacting google a second time I resolved this issue.  I needed to enable "access to less secure apps" from the my google admin account.  This is found under "Security" -> "Basic Settings"  ->  "Go to settings for less secure apps" ->  "Allow Users to Manager Their Access to Less Secure Apps"

Comment: I'm delighted that you have a solution. Perhaps you would write it as an answer so that others with a similar problem can be helped?

Answer (score 1):

After contacting google a second time I resolved this issue. I needed to enable "access to less secure apps" from the my google admin account. This is found under "Security" -> "Basic Settings" -> "Go to settings for less secure apps" -> "Allow Users to Manager Their Access to Less Secure Apps"

Comment: For me, this setting was already in place, however the users had their personal setting to "not allow less secure apps" by default, which was causing the problems. So I changed my setting to "force access to less secure apps" and problem solved.